# Spring RequestMapping multiple paths with pathVaruable

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a method like this

```
@PutMapping(value = {"/something/{id}", "/otherThing/{username}"})
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Object>> toggle(@PathVariable(name = "id", required = false) Long ssoId,
                                                   @PathVariable(name = "username", required = false) String username)
```

but when I send a request to "/otherThing/myUsername" it get Bad Request error with this message

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: myUsername
```

Comment: Here ssoId is required path var. This is not the right way to do it. You can split them into diff methods and call a common overloading method inside them .

Comment: Here you found many ways for optional path var https://www.baeldung.com/spring-optional-path-variables